# Capybara: Session lost when adding a setTimeout on form.submit()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

Rails v4.2.7

I have a rails form (**not remote**) with a submit button with this event attached for both preventing a double submission, and showing a better feedback for the user (basically what `data-disable-with` would do for a remote form):

```coffee
    $('#my-submit-button').on "click", ->
      this.disabled = "disabled"
      this.value = "Loading..."
      $(this).removeClass("button-active-class")
      $(this).addClass("button-busy-class")

      myForm = this.form
      setTimeout ->
        myForm.submit()
      , 500
```

The reason for the `setTimeout` is that if I instantly submit the form, for some reason in Safari the style changes are not applied.

**This works great.**

however, I have a Capybara test (which uses headless_chrome) like this:

```rb
sign_in user

visit my_page_path

# fill in form

find("#my-submit-button").click

expect(page).to have_content "some content"
```

For some reason I noticed the `current_user` was being set to `nil` after the form was submitted, so I added a log for cookies as a `before_filter` in my ApplicationController:

```rb
def my_before_filter
  p cookies.first
end
```

And the output was effectively showing me two different cookies between the visit, and the request triggered by the form submission.
So I removed the `setTimeout` in order to submit the form instantly:

```coffee
    $('#my-submit-button').on "click", ->
      # [...]

      # myForm = this.form
      # setTimeout ->
        # myForm.submit()
      # , 500

      this.form.submit()
```

And now, even though the styling is not correctly applied after clicking on the button, the test passes and cookies are the same.

Any idea what's going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is a guess based on the the assumption your `sign_in` method actually visits the page, fills in the login info and submits the form.  It your `sign_in` method is actually a shortcut via something like the devise warden test mode this won't be correct.

It sounds like your `$('#my-submit-button')` is also being applied to the submit button on the login form. By delaying that half a second (seems like a long time to delay) the driver no longer detects that the actions done in `sign_in` are triggering a page transition and therefore doesn't wait for it. This means the `visit my_page_path` gets executed before login has completed and the correct cookies have been returned. Your `sign_in` method should have a positive expectation at the end of it for something on the page that indicates logging in has completed along the lines of

```
expect(page).to have_text('You are logged in!')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I don't think that's the problem because the visit is working fine, It's properly signing in the user, and when filling the form, I even use Select2 with an ajax request with works well. The only issue is the request triggered by clicking on the submit button. And that's only happening with the setTimeout. In addition to all of that, effectively, the `sign_in` is just doing a `page.set_rack_session(user_id: user.id)` (we are using zuul gem for auth). Do you have any other idea? Or is any other information I can provide or tip for me to dig?

Comment: @ascherman As stated in my note - if my assumption wasn't correct the answer wouldn't be either :) - Does actually declaring myForm as a local variable `var myForm = this.form` make a difference?

Comment: @ascherman Beyond that check your test log and see if the csrf protection tokens are actually being sent with the form submission. Another thing to check would be that you have actually prevented the default click behavior when setting the timeout.